# What's wrong with my solution to K&R exercise 1-22?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Exercise 1-22 of *The C Programming Language* is as follow:

> Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter
>   lines after  the last non-blank character that occurs before the *n*-th
>   column of input. Make sure your  program does something intelligent
>   with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs  before the
>   specified column.

This is the code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 500
#define FOLD_LENGTH 15

/* _getline:  read a line into s, return length  */ 
size_t _getline(char s[], int lim) 
{ 
    int c; 
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) 
        s[i] = c; 
    if (c == '\n') { 
        s[i] = c; 
        ++i; 
    } 
    s[i] = '\0'; 
    return i; 
}

int main()
{
    int c;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char temp;
    unsigned last_space_idx = 0, i, offset = 0;

    while (_getline(line, MAXLINE) != 0) {
        for (i = 0; line[offset+i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (i == FOLD_LENGTH) {
                temp = line[offset+last_space_idx];
                line[offset+last_space_idx] = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", line+offset);
                line[offset+last_space_idx] = temp;
                offset = last_space_idx;
                i = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (isspace(line[offset+i])) {
                last_space_idx = offset+i;
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n", line+offset);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the sample input I'm using:

```
Penny Lane is in my ears and in my eyes
There beneath
the blue suburban skies
```

And this is the output I get:

```
Penny Lane is
 in my ears and in my ey
 and in my eyes

 eyes

 eyes

 eyes
```

What's the bug here? I really have no clue.

Comment: I must ask: are you using ANSI color codes to turn "Penny Lane" light blue? That could really throw things off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lots of errors.  You do this:

```
last_space_idx = offset+i;
```

But you also do this:

```
temp = line[offset+last_space_idx];
```

Which means that `temp = line[(2 * offset) + last_observed_space_relative_to_offset]`.

You also do this:

```
offset = last_space_idx;
```

That means the offset becomes equal to the last observed space, so you'll have a preceding space on every line after the first, like this:

```
Penny lane is
 in my ears
 and in my eyes
```

Your _getline() method does this:

```
if (c == '\n') { 
    s[i] = c; 
    ++i; 
}
```

That means any line returns are preserved, so if you have `There beneath\nthe blue suburban skies` as the input you'll get this output:

```
There beneath

the blue suburban skies
```

Lastly, each new line you read uses the last space index and offset from the previous line.  You need to reset them before the `for` loop starts.

Here's a fixed version.  I've tidied up the style a little and replaced the printf() bodge with a string format that will print a substring.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 500
#define FOLD_LENGTH 15

size_t _getline(char s[], int lim);

/* _getline:  read a line into s, return length  */ 
size_t _getline(char s[], int lim) {

    char c; 
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    s[i] = '\0'; 
    return i; 
}

int main() {

    char line[MAXLINE];
    unsigned last_space_idx = 0;
    unsigned i;
    unsigned offset = 0;

    while (_getline(line, MAXLINE) != 0) {

        last_space_idx = 0;
        offset = 0;

        for (i = 0; line[offset+i] != '\0'; ++i) {
            if (i == FOLD_LENGTH) {
                printf("%.*s\n", last_space_idx, line + offset);
                offset += last_space_idx + 1;
                i = 0;
            } else if (isspace(line[offset + i])) {
                last_space_idx = i;
            }
        }

        printf("%s\n", line + offset);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 For the `printf` format string. I've never seen a length specifier written like that.